# A quarter note or an eighths?

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music

Maybe a beginner question - but can't find any information on this and have no one to ask!

On the image below - how is the first note meant to be played? How can it be both an eighths and a quarter?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hold the first note for one beat.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, this note is written that the player should hold it as long as the value is written, and it can be accented, that means playing it a little bit higher as for example the melody line. While the other notes are played normal further. You can find examples of such kind of notation in Chopin piano music or in Tchaikovsky piano concerto no.1. If you get your hands on these. But that's already a lot higher level of playing.